# why is my if statement outputting the wrong thing?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make the code on line 18 work, its supposed to put me into line 19 if I input 8 but it just says the code that it is supposed to say if you put something I haven't prepared yet.

```
import random
import time
stealth = random.randint(1, 20)
strength = random.randint(1, 20)
dexterity = random.randint(1, 20)
charisma = random.randint(1, 20)
constitution = random.randint(1, 20)
wisdom = random.randint(1, 20)
intelligence = random.randint(1, 20) 
play = True
if play == False:
     exit

if input('Welcome to Cannible Island Cruise! \nWould you like to board?').lower() == 'yes':
    print('Great! Have a great time!')
    time.sleep(2)
    if input('To your left you see several stories acsending into the sky, and to your right you see a pool. Where would you like to go?').lower() == 'left':
        if input('you see a elevator with buttons one through eight, which floor would you like to go to? You are currently on the fifth floor.').lower() ==8:
            if input('You see the captain working at the controls of the ship, he seems confused. What would you like to do?').lower() == 'hit captain':
                if input('you punch the captain and he is knocked out cold, roll for stealth').lower() == 'ok':
                    print(f'You got a {stealth}!')
                    if stealth < 20:
                        play = True
                        q1 = input('someone saw you from the window! you better run before they tell the guards!')
                        if q1.lower() == 'run':
                            play = True
                            print('Oh no! Youve been caught!\n GAME OVER')
                        else:
                            play = False
                        input('I do not recognise that command. Try again')
                        if play == False:
                                exit()
        else: print('not yet programmed')
```

I tried to rewrite the line of code, I tried to use different ways to make it work, but it just does the same thing.

Comment: Typo?  Does the input equal `8`?  Or does it equal `'8'`?  Everywhere else you compare it with a string except on the one line that "doesn't work".

Comment: `input()` always returns a string.  So `input() == 8` will never be true.

Comment: Why do you use `lower()` if you're comparing with a number? What difference does it make whether it's uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: `play` cannot be false if in the previous line you just declared it true. Also it should be `exit()` and not `exit`